# Expanding Auto Sorting to Second Column

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that auto-sorts column D on a spreadsheet and it works perfectly. But, how can I get it to sort a second column?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    Range("D1").Sort Key1:=Range("D1"), _
      Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
      OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
      Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by second column exactly as you've sorted on the first one.

Just keep in mind, that - exactly as for manual sorting - if you want your data to be sorted by column D then by column E, then you need to **sort first by column C**.

Comment: If I add another sort just like the one I have it sorts by D and then ignores the first sort entirely and sorts the other column.

Comment: can you please add screenshot and explain what's wrong? it's not clear.